# How to make url parameter value to be url link via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, parameters

I want to make a website page, say the domain like this `http://www.test.com`. In this web, i have page `http://www.test.com/page1.html?bounce=http://www.test.com/page2.html`.

I want to make button link in the /page1.html which linked to /page2.html using javascript? How i can do that using url parameters info like this

```
http://www.test.com/page1.html?bounce=http://www.test.com/page2.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to navigate to a new page in JS is:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.test.com/page2.html';
```

However, if you need to gain access to GET parameters within a browser's URL using pure JS, that's something else entirely.  See [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters) for a detailed solution.